# GitLab Upload Issue (trying to upload an existing Eclipse project to GitLab)

Tags: spring, git, eclipse, spring-mvc, gitlab

I read multiple SO questions. But, I couldn't solve my problem. :-(

These are 3 methods I tried.

> **# Method 1**

**[STEP 1]** [*Eclipse / Project Explorer*] Create a project

(*NOTE* : Default Location : **eclipse-workspace**)

[image: ab]

**[STEP 2]** [*Eclipse / Project Explorer*] Configure a git repository

[image]

**[STEP 3]** [*GitLab*] Create a project & Clone with HTTPS

**[STEP 4]** [*Eclipse / Project Explorer*] Right Click > Team > Share Project

**[STEP 5]** [*Eclipse / Git Repositories*] Right Click > Commit

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

> **# Method 2**

**[STEP 1]** [*Eclipse / Project Explorer*] Create a project

(*NOTE* : I created a folder inside of the **git** folder)

[image]

**Repeated the rest of steps in the Method 1 and failed again...**

[image]

---

> ## Method 3

**[STEP 1]** [*Eclipse / Project Explorer*] Create a project

(*NOTE* : Default Location : **eclipse-workspace**)

**[STEP 2]** [*Eclipse / Project Explorer*] Configure a git repository

**[STEP 3]** [*GitLab*] Create a project & Clone with HTTPS

**[STEP 4]** [*Eclipse / Project Explorer*] Right Click > Team > Share Project

[image]

[image]

(**The problem is that "test3" is inside of "test3". I just want one folder, not one folder inside of another folder with the same name......**)

**[STEP 5]** [*Eclipse / Git Repositories*] Right Click > Commit

[image]

[image]

(**I don't want to have the project folder inside of the project folder...**)

[image]

(**I can see the files after clicking "test3" folder... I want to see these not inside of the "test3" folder... **)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by taking almost same steps to Method 1. The only difference was STEP 5. Maybe that made a difference...

---

**[STEP 1]** [*Eclipse / Project Explorer*] Create a project

(*NOTE* : Default Location : **eclipse-workspace**)

[image]

**[STEP 2]** [*Eclipse / Project Explorer*] Right Click > Team > Share Project

[image]

**[STEP 3]** [*Eclipse / Project Explorer*] Configure a git repository

**[STEP 4]** [*GitLab*] Create a project & Clone with HTTPS

**[STEP 5]** [*Eclipse / Git Repositories*] Commit & Push

[image]

[image]